# How to avoid duplicate initializing when adopting protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols

I know I can do this with super class, but Swift doesn’t support **abstract** class, and I wanna use protocol instead. However, when there are many property requirements, I find it really hard to avoid duplicate `self.xxx = xxx` code.. Example:

```swift
protocol ManyProperties {
    var a: Int { get }
    var b: Int { get }
    var c: Int { get }
    var d: Int { get }
}

struct S: ManyProperties {
    let a: Int
    let b: Int
    let c: Int
    let d: Int

    init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
    }
}

class C: ManyProperties {
    let a: Int
    let b: Int
    let c: Int
    let d: Int

    // duplicate initializing
    init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
    }
}
```

I really want to type something like `super.init()` and I **do not want inheritance**. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Structs has a free memberwise initializer, so you don't need to write this kind of `init` for them:

```
struct S: ManyProperties {
    let a, b, c, d: Int
}
```

but for the class you have some options:

1- Use base class and inherit from it instead of conforming to protocol:

```
class ManyPropertiesClass: ManyProperties {
    let a: Int
    let b: Int
    let c: Int
    let d: Int

    // duplicate initializing
    init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
    }
}

class C: ManyPropertiesClass {
}
```

2- Add `init` inside the protocol, so it forces you to implement it with a little autocompletion help

```
protocol ManyProperties: class {
    var a: Int { get }
    var b: Int { get }
    var c: Int { get }
    var d: Int { get }

    init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int)}
}
```

3- define another initializer inside the protocol and make variables `set`able so the compiler knows that all properties are initialized. Then you can extend the protocol to have the initializer:

```
protocol ManyProperties: class {
    var a: Int { get set }
    var b: Int { get set }
    var c: Int { get set }
    var d: Int { get set }

    init()
}

extension ManyProperties {
    init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
    }
}

class C: ManyProperties {
    var a: Int = 0
    var b: Int = 0
    var c: Int = 0
    var d: Int = 0

    required init() {}
}
```